# std::wstring sFile in java

Tags: java, c++, polymorphism, game-engine, wrapper

I am working on making a game in java and I want to use an engine ([olcConsoleGameEngine](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/videos/blob/master/olcConsoleGameEngine.h)) that was coded in c++ but I want to make it in java. I can wrap my head around most of the way that c++ is coded but I am stuck on a specific line (198): `olcSprite(std::wstring sFile)`.

```
class olcSprite
{
public:
    olcSprite()
    {

    }

    olcSprite(int w, int h)
    {
        Create(w, h);
    }

    olcSprite(std::wstring sFile)     // line 198
    {
        if (!Load(sFile))
            Create(8, 8);
    }

    //...
```

I looked up and found out that `std::function` is a "general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper" according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function. but I'm not sure what that means or how to specifically implement an equivalent for my case in java. if anyone could either help me understand this better or point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: *I can wrap my head around most of the way that c++ is coded* -- I suggest you actually know C++.  Trying to figure out a complex language like C++ on a line-by-line basis rarely, if ever, works out correctly.

Comment: Isn't wstring just UTF8 Unicode?  Two byte character string instead of single byte characters.  Java Strings are Unicode by default, so you're all set.

Comment: I don't see what line 198 has got to do with `std::function`?

Comment: @duffymo No, `std::wstring` uses `wchar_t`'s instead of `char`. It doesn't really say much about the encoding.

Comment: The key is two bytes per character versus one, regardless of encoding.  Still not pertinent?  Java Strings are always two bytes per character - no choice.

Comment: @duffymo Hard to say. `std::wstring` is often used for UTF-16LE encoded strings in Windows. If some interoperability is needed some care should be taken - but if the translated game engine is going to run standalone, I'm guessing that  whatever encoding java uses doesn't matter, it'll be fine as you said.

Comment: `std::wstring` uses `wchar_t`, which is 2 bytes (UCS-2/UTF-16) on Windows, but is 4 bytes (UCS-4/UTF-32) on other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

When you look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/) you find:

```
std::wstring
typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring;
Wide string
String class for wide characters.
```

In other word: that is a constructor that **simply** takes string, and that string represents a file name, which then is used to do file system stuff.

The only "special" thing here, it is a string with "wide chars", see [there](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wide-char-and-library-functions-in-c/).

None of your code uses std::function though. That is all there is to this, this is a constructor of the `olcSprite` class that probably reads bytes for the "sprite" from disc.